# An example of a function which is (locally) above its tangents but is not convex

Tags: calculus

I am looking for an example of a function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, continuous in $[a,b]$, differentaible in $(a,b)$, such that for any $a<t<b$ there is some open interval $t\in I\subseteq (a,b)$ such that $f(x)\geq f(t)+f'(t)(x-t)$ for any $x\in I$, but $f$ is not convex in $[a,b]$; Thanks.

Comment: Convex differentiable function is a function with monotone (increasing) derivative. If you formulate your requirement on $f'$, I think you're asking for a continuous function, monotone around every point, but not monotone in the whole interval. I don't think that works, considering local minima...

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Consider the following

*Lemma*. Suppose $g\colon (a,b)\to\Bbb R$ is locally increasing at each point. Then $g$ is increasing.

(A least upper bound argument gives the proof.)

I don't believe there is an example of such an $f$.

Comment: Thanks. I am actually glad there is no such $f$ :)

Comment: You're welcome. If you're satisfied with the answer, please accept it so that the question will go off the "unanswered" list. :)